# Windows Server more application with different address

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis, server

I have one, maybe easy question. I have my .NET application on Windows Server. Is there any possibility how run the next application on another url? I normally use different ports on testing application. But now I need next application with port 80.

For example, I have a server with IP 80.1.2.3.
Now is running their application with the url test.com
And I want to add new application to the url anothertest.com

Is it possible?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. do you want multiple domain names to share an IP address? If so then the answer is yes. If I misunderstand your requirement, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: @samwu You got it. And can you tell me how i can do it? Thanks

Comment: If you learn what are IIS site bindings, you can help yourself, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below steps:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node in the tree, and then select the site for which you want to configure a host header.
3. In the Actions pane, click Bindings.
4. In the Site Bindings dialog box, select the binding for which you want to add a host header and then click Edit or click Add to add a new binding with a host header.
5. In the Host name box, type a host header for the site, such as `test.com`.
6. Click OK.
7. To add an additional host header, create a new binding with the same IP address and port, and the new host header. Repeat for each host header that you want to use this IP address and port.